# How to create custom component using JSF 1.2?

Tags: jsf

I am new in the JSF world, please tell me step by step answer of how to create JSF custom component i search on the net but i didn't get any proper answer or give me some link which shows how to create custom component.

Thanks
Vinod

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Googling for ["extend UIComponentELTag"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22extend+UIComponentELTag%22) or ["extends UIComponentELTag"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22extends+UIComponentELTag%22) should yield enough hints.

This is one of my favourites: http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/2006/12/jsf-component-writing-check-list/

Answer (score 0):

RichFaces includes CDK (component development kit) that can be used for components development.
Here is the link to the guide: [RichFaces CDK Developer Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/cdkguide/html_single/index.html)